# NopCommerce deployment decision

Tags: azure-web-app-service, nopcommerce

I have installed NopCommerce from the Azure Websites gallery.  It is up and configured which is great, albeit not the latest version.  Moving forwards, I want to customise it quite heavily, but it would be nice to increment from what I have up and working rather than from scratch.

Whilst there is docs out there for each, I can't work out how I retrofit this solution.  I have Visual Studio without a current project and a Azure Website with a fully working solution from the gallery.  I can't work out how to join the two together and give me full ability to customise presumably with source in the project?

Comment: Does your Azure site having customized code?

Comment: Not right now it is a basic install with demo data, I do however need to customise it a fair bit.  The basic install does connect to my database and work which is a good base from my point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the question, simply I understood is you're having one deployed website code and *not having the source code of it.* And you want to do some customization in to it.

It's not possible to do customize using deployed code anyway.You should have the source code.

If you want to do some customization then simply download [`Source code` of nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/downloads.aspx)

And open it from Visual studio, customize it, published it and then deploy it on Azure.

---

Or if you don't want to deploy updated changes then you can develop your plugin and install it on your azure site.

**Update:**

[There are several ways to Installing NopCommerce on Windows Azure](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/en/Installing+on+Windows+Azure)

Currently, you're being used is *Web platform installer* and all you have to use is *Visual Studio - web deploy*

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, let me give it a go.  Sounds like I need to setup Visual studio manually with source, then treat the publish as an update so I don't lose data/config  etc from the 'out of the box' deploy Azure did for me.